# How to convert BIGINT Timestamp to a Datetime in dbeaver

Tags: amazon-redshift, bigint

I connected my redshift to dbeaver and while running select * on my table i got in the time column - 1541079087394 which is bigint. how can i shel run the query in order to get time stamp with date and time like in kibana - May 20th 2019, 10:49:16.949.

Answer (score 2):

Time columns are not bigint, however you probably can convert that integer to a timestamp using this code method

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + your_bigint_col/1000  * interval '1 second' AS your_column_alias
from your_table
```

This is assuming that your bigint is epoch, you didn't say.